# Monitor Resolutions not detected - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I just recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my PC. For some reason, there's only one resolution detected for my monitors (1024 x 768 :: 4:3) and no other option to change to. It's also only detecting my central monitor and neither of my other monitors. The monitor also shows up as "unknown display". I've already tried running the `xrandr` commands to try and fix it, but each time, I get a "Failed to get size of gamma for output default" error. I've already tried manually updating my nvidia drivers and installing Geforce, but that installation threw an unknown error and failed. I've been all over the internet and tried everything, but nothing's working and I'm about to lose it.

System specs:

- Ryzen 5 2600
- MSI RTX 3070
- MSI B450 Tomahawk MAX
- 16GB Corsair Vengeance RAM

Comment: Try installing the NVIDIA drivers by running `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`.  It should download and install tested NVIDIA drivers for you automatically.  I do recommend that you disable Secure Boot in your BIOS first before you install NVIDIA drivers or they will fail.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu version 20 what is the REAL version?

Comment: Title says ubuntu 20.04